# Debugging TS in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, typescript, gulp, webpack, webstorm

Server starts through gulp. In Run Configuration I've created a JavaScript Debug and set server url. Extension in Chrome is available. As a build system I use Webpack. In Debugging mode I can see that connection is successful but breakpoints are not working.

Comment: I found out that if breakpoint is set in compiled file then breakpoint is working and next steps being transferred into ts files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need setting up Remote URL mappings in your JavaScript Debug run configuration accordingly. Please see http://richb-hanover.com/debugging-webpack-apps-with-webstorm-2016-1/, https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/ for some hints